# github authentication when pushing

Tags: git, macos, https, raspbian, ssh-keys

Whenever I push to my github account on my mac I do not need to enter email/password every time.  I only entered it the one time.  However, when I push on my RPi (running Raspbian OS) it asks for my username/password every time.  I understand I can set up ssh keys to circumvent this issue, but I'd rather use https as it's, as far as I know, more secure.  The thing is, on my mac the repo is setup with https anyway, but still doesn't ask for credentials every time.  What is the issue here?

Comment: Why do you think HTTPS is more secure than SSH?

Comment: I thought the standard these days is https.  Could be wrong about which is more secure.  The other issue is when running git init it will default to https, so I would have to manually go in and change to ssh every time in the config file.  Unless there is a way to default to ssh.

Comment: `git init` doesn't create any remotes; how could it possibly "default to" HTTPS _or_ SSH?

Comment: wow!  that was a slip.  you're of course right.  I must have been thinking this command: `'git remote add origin'`.  which isn't much of a problem adding in either https or ssh.  Still would be nice to figure out why it works on one os not the other.